# CSS modification to arrange pointer

Tags: html, css, styles, position

I have a css tooltip on my html. I get the arrow mark`(bubble:after)` at the bottom of my bubble. How can I re-arrange to right center of my bubble?

Here is my `div`

```
 <div class="bubble">Hi there. I like turtles.</div>
<p style="margin-left: 1em;">Mikey sez</p>
```

The bubble which is displayed on my div is from the css below

```
 <style type="text/css">
 .bubble {
 position: relative;
 background-color:#eee;
 margin: 0;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:180px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
}
.bubble:after {    //This after mark has to be arranged so to point to the right of bubble
position: absolute;  //The position should be at the center
display: block;
content: "";  
border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
height:0;
width:0;
position:absolute;
bottom:-19px;
left:1em;
 }
```

[image: Bubble with bubble after]

Rearrange like below image

[image: To be rearranged like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/xy9Gb/). All you need to do is change the absolute positioning of the `::after` element, and switch which border has a colour, from this:

```
border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
bottom:-19px;
left:1em;
```

To this:

```
border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;
bottom:25%;
right:-19px;
```

Comment: This solution might work for that particular case, but if you decide to increase the `bubble` size or padding the layout will break.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick, http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/hu38A/1

```
.bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /* border-width */
    right: -20px; /* border-width*2; */
}
```

Comment: That din't do the trick exactly. That positioned the anchor right in the center. I need it to the right of bubble and v-align center.

Comment: @oneofthelions rather than just copying and pasting in the code, you should have added it yourself and tried to understand it. The reason it did not work were that the comments weren't escaped for CSS.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. Just pasted it here and it works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/hu38A/1/. I fixed the comments that were in JS fomart, that might've been the problem. As **My Head Hurts** says, it's better if you write it yourself. You'll learn more this way.